How to read a data from text file with stacked columns?
I am trying to import a data set from a .txt file in R. The data is a 200x200 matrix/dataframe. However, the columns are stacked. I was unable to read and reshape it to actual 200x200 matrix. Part of the data is shown below.
Any help is apprecieted.
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
  [1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [2,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [3,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [4,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [5,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [6,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
  [1,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [2,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [3,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [4,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [5,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [6,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1

I tried readLines function, but was unable to fix it.

If files are structured as in included sample, perhaps something like this would do:
library(readr)
txt <- 
"      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
  [1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [2,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [3,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [4,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [5,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [6,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
      [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25]
  [1,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [2,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [3,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [4,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [5,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
  [6,]    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
"

l <- read_lines(txt)

# generate intervals from header row indices, split to list;
split(l, findInterval(seq_along(l), grep("\\[,\\d+\\]", l))) |>
  # read table content from list items, drop 1st columns;
  lapply(\(x) read_table(x, skip = 1, col_names = FALSE)[,-1]) |>
  # bind columns
  do.call(what = cbind)
#>   1.X2 1.X3 1.X4 1.X5 1.X6 1.X7 1.X8 1.X9 1.X10 1.X11 1.X12 1.X13 1.X14 2.X2
#> 1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#> 2   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#> 3   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#> 4   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#> 5   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#> 6   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1    -1   -1
#>   2.X3 2.X4 2.X5 2.X6 2.X7 2.X8 2.X9 2.X10 2.X11 2.X12 2.X13
#> 1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
#> 2   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
#> 3   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
#> 4   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
#> 5   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1
#> 6   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1    -1    -1    -1    -1

Created on 2024-06-07 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you! That worked perfectly. It was a great help.
